# ClankBundle - WebSocket in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I try to use webscoket in my symfony project. I found this bundle, but i can't setup it.

https://github.com/JDare/ClankBundle

My ChatTopic.php

```
<?php

namespace My\ChatBundle\Topic;

use JDare\ClankBundle\Topic\TopicInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface as Conn;

class ChatTopic implements TopicInterface
{

    /**
     * This will receive any Subscription requests for this topic.
     *
     * @param \Ratchet\ConnectionInterface $conn
     * @param $topic
     * @return void
     */
    public function onSubscribe(Conn $conn, $topic)
    {
        //this will broadcast the message to ALL subscribers of this topic.
        $topic->broadcast($conn->resourceId . " has joined " . $topic->getId());
    }

    /**
     * This will receive any UnSubscription requests for this topic.
     *
     * @param \Ratchet\ConnectionInterface $conn
     * @param $topic
     * @return void
     */
    public function onUnSubscribe(Conn $conn, $topic)
    {
        //this will broadcast the message to ALL subscribers of this topic.
        $topic->broadcast($conn->resourceId . " has left " . $topic->getId());
    }


    /**
     * This will receive any Publish requests for this topic.
     *
     * @param \Ratchet\ConnectionInterface $conn
     * @param $topic
     * @param $event
     * @param array $exclude
     * @param array $eligible
     * @return mixed|void
     */
    public function onPublish(Conn $conn, $topic, $event, array $exclude, array $eligible)
    {
        /*
        $topic->getId() will contain the FULL requested uri, so you can proceed based on that

        e.g.

        if ($topic->getId() == "acme/channel/shout")
            //shout something to all subs.
        */


        $topic->broadcast(array(
            "sender" => $conn->resourceId,
            "topic" => $topic->getId(),
            "event" => $event
        ));
    }

}
```

Now my services

```
my_chat.chat_topic_handle:
        class: My\ChatBundle\Topic\ChatTopic
```

config

```
# Clank Configuration
clank:
    web_socket_server:
        port: 8080        #The port the socket server will listen on
        host: 127.0.0.1   #(optional) The host ip to bind to
    topic:
        -
            name: "chat"
            service: "my_chat.chat_topic_handle"
```

This is my js code:

```
var myClank = Clank.connect("ws://localhost:8080");

myClank.on("socket/connect", function(session){

    session.publish("chat/channel", {msg: "This is a message!"});

    //the callback function in "subscribe" is called everytime an event is published in that channel.
    session.subscribe("chat/channel", function(uri, payload){
        console.log("Received message", payload.msg);
    });

    session.unsubscribe("chat/channel");

    session.publish("chat/channel", {msg: "I won't see this"});
})

myClank.on("socket/disconnect", function(error){
    //error provides us with some insight into the disconnection: error.reason and error.code

    console.log("Disconnected for " + error.reason + " with code " + error.code);
})
```

After refreshing page i have nothing from websocket in my console. Webscoket connects with server,  but I think that my ChatTopic.php doesn't work, and I don't know why. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your js code.

You connect to socket, subscribe to "chat/channel" and immediately unsubscribe. This prevents you from receiving any message.

You should, in order:

1. subscribe
2. publish
3. never unsubscribe (or at least, I still did not find a reason to do so)

By the way, you do not have to "refresh the page", you should open two browser pages on the same url: when the second loads you should see a message in the other one too.